# Java Spring Annotation equivalent of reference

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I am attempting to move from the XML configuration, and am confused about what the equivalent of 
`<spring:property name="beanName" ref="beanToReference">`

I thought it would be something similar to the `@Value("${Property.Value}")` annotation

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can reference it like this:

```
@Bean
MyAnotherBean myAnotherBean() {
    return new MyAnotherBean();
}

@Bean
MyBean myBean(MyAnotherBean beanToReference) {
    final MyBean myBean = new MyBean();
    myBean.setAnotherBean(beanToReference);
    return myBean;
}
```

Or like this (in case both beans in the same configuration class):

```
@Bean
MyAnotherBean myAnotherBean() {
    return new MyAnotherBean();
}

@Bean
MyBean myBean() {
    final MyBean myBean = new MyBean();
    myBean.setAnotherBean(myAnotherBean());
    return myBean;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that you have two beans like this

```
@Compenent
public class SampleBeanOne{
}

@Compenent
public class SampleBeanTwo{
}
```

and you want to use them like you define in your xml file in the main component

```
@Compenent
public class MainComponent{

    @Autowired
    private SampleBeanOne sampleBeanOne;         

    @Autowired
    private SampleBeanTwo sampleBeanTwo;         

}
```

First things first you should enable @Autowired annotation like this

```
<beans  
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
</beans>
```

Once annotation injection is enabled, autowiring can be used on properties, setters, and constructors.

By default, Spring uses @Autowired by type. If you have more than one beans of the same type, the framework will throw an exception indicating that more than one bean is available for autowiring. for resolving that you can use @Qualifier annotation.

Spring uses the bean name as a default qualifier value so if you use it like this :

```
    @Autowired
    private SampleBeanOne myBean;
```

it assumes that you have MyBean implementation of SampleBeanOne and try to fine and inject it on your component construction.